# Simplifying complex-valued entries in a matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, complex

I have a matrix where some entries are complex or roots of unity. For example,

```
(-1)^(2/9) - (-1)^(5/9) + (-1)^(8/9)
```

is one such entry and it is equal to 0.

When I send such an entry to Wolfram|Alpha, it gives me zero. But I have matrix full of such identities, so I want to do the simplification on the whole matrix and inside Mathematica.

Is there is anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a few approaches:

```
FullSimplify[(-1)^(2/9) - (-1)^(5/9) + (-1)^(8/9)]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

```
Simplify[ExpToTrig[(-1)^(2/9) - (-1)^(5/9) + (-1)^(8/9)]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

```
PossibleZeroQ[(-1)^(2/9) - (-1)^(5/9) + (-1)^(8/9)]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: so FullySimplify work for Matrix too? thanks

Comment: It threads over lists, yes.

Comment: I tried it.. and its work.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
      Simplify[ComplexExpand[(-1)^(2/9) - (-1)^(5/9) + (-1)^(8/9)]]
 (*  0  *)
```